# Detecting the language used in template by Django Template

Tags: python, django, html, django-models, django-templates

is it possible that Django realize which language are used in template and change element of HTML direction and align? for example, I want sometimes use Persian in one element, and another time I want to use English in there, which both of them are gotten by database.
In addition I don't want to manipulate each element one by one; I want general solution for whole template.

```
<p style="direction: ltr">Hi!<p>
```

Sometimes:

```
<p style="direction: rtl">Hi!<p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: How to get language code in template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265077/django-how-to-get-language-code-in-template)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.
For example, in your template

```
{% load i18n %}
...
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}
<div class='one-direction'>test</div>
{% else %}
<div class='another-direction'>test</div>
{% endif %}
```

Add styles for classes in your css file.

to see more about getting language code:

[Django: How to get language code in template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265077/django-how-to-get-language-code-in-template)

== Update ==

@altruistic, 
add dynamic css class to body element and  add styles for p element. For example:

```
body.one-direction p:  direction: rtl
body.another-direction p:  direction: ltr
```

So, you need to check language only once

Comment: This is a good solution, but, doing this for each element is a little time-consuming, there is no general solution?

Comment: @altruistic , if you would have added more information to your question, we would have considered other options. As it is, this is the best answer to your question.

Comment: @rnevius, Thanks for your inflexibility!